# Do I need to have an ETA if I am getting work permit?

Tags: canada

As I will be going to Canada to work, while I understand that I will need to go to the immigration checkpoint to get my permit, do I need to get an ETA beforehand?

Answer (score 4):

No - if you need an ETA they will issue it with your workpermit
[See CIC website here](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=206&top=16)